# How to Set Longtable Multicolumn Spesific Rows to the Next Page

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

Based on my question [How to Fix Longtable Multicolumn that Splitted on the Next Page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582434/how-to-fix-longtable-multicolumn-that-splitted-on-the-next-page?noredirect=1#comment1466582_582434), now I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2cm},vmargin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{-1.2cm}{0.7cm}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{2ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat{\section}
[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesection}{1ex}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Random Text}
    \section{Section Name}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begingroup
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|p{9cm}|}
        \caption{Random text for caption here.}
        \label{table1} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Head1}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Head2}}   \\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{Random text for caption here. (Continue)} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Head1}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Head2}}   \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{3}{r @{}}{\small\emph{continue on the next page}} \\*
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        %%%% table nody    
        1&Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&\lipsum[4]\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \hline
        2&Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&\lipsum[4]\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \endgroup
    \section{Section Name 2}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I want to make the row circled in red on the next page, how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution, you can add `\newpage` in the row that you want to move in the next page. You can get the last line on previous page move in next page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2cm},vmargin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{-1.2cm}{0.7cm}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{2ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat{\section}
[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesection}{1ex}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Random Text}
    \section{Section Name}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begingroup
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|p{9cm}|}
        \caption{Random text for caption here.}
        \label{table1} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Head1}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Head2}}   \\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{Random text for caption here. (Continue)} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Head1}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Head2}}   \\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{3}{r @{}}{\small\emph{continue on the next page}} \\*
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        %%%% table nody    
        1&Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&\lipsum[4]\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \hline
        \newpage
        2&Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&\lipsum[4]\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \cline{2-3}
        &Text2&Long text here.\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \endgroup
    \section{Section Name 2}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]